# Is a subscript to an indexed array an arithmetic expansion?

Tags: bash

Quoting from the Bash manual:

> An indexed array is created automatically if any variable is assigned
>   to using the syntax
>
> ```
> name[subscript]=value
> ```
>
> **The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must
>   evaluate to a number.**

Is `subscript`

- an arithmetic expression, or
- an arithmetic expansion where `$((` and `))` are ignored and only an arithmetic expression is there?

In other words, is there a step of arithmetic expansion here, just like when interpreting a command with arithmetic expansion?

For example,

```
$ declare -p myarr
declare -a myarr='([0]="0" [2]="3" [3]="9999")'

$ echo ${myarr[1+2]}
9999
$ echo ${myarr[$((1+2))]}
9999
```

Comment: Are you asking if your demonstration (the first echo command) is true?

Comment: No. I am asking the questions I asked. The example is to show that explicit arith expansion works.

Comment: You ask if subscript is an arithmetic expansion, then show that it is. It seems self-answered?

Comment: Two ways that achieve the same thing are not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a step of arithmetic expansion [with array subscripts], just like when interpreting a command with arithmetic expansion?

Yes.

Variable expansion:

```
$ unset -v a
$ declare -p a
-bash: declare: a: not found
$ x=4
$ a[x]=4
$ declare -p a
declare -a a='([4]="4")'
```

Parameter expansion:

```
$ six=six
$ a[${#six}]=3
$ declare -p a
declare -a a='([3]="3" [4]="4")'
```

Command substitution:

```
$ a[$(echo 9)]=9
$ declare -p a
declare -a a='([3]="3" [4]="4" [9]="9")'
```

Quote removal:

```
$ a["5"]=5
$ declare -p a
declare -a a='([3]="3" [4]="4" [5]="5" [9]="9")'
$ a['6']=6
$ declare -p a
declare -a a='([3]="3" [4]="4" [5]="5" [6]="6" [9]="9")'
$ a[\7]=7
$ declare -p a
declare -a a='([3]="3" [4]="4" [5]="5" [6]="6" [7]="7" [9]="9")'
```

[Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)

> 3.5.5 Arithmetic Expansion
>
> All tokens in the expression undergo parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, and quote removal.

Answer (score 0):

> - Is a subscript to an indexed array an arithmetic expansion?

To be precise: No, it is an "arithmetic expression", identical to what is inside an "arithmetic expansion" but lacks the `$(( ))`.

Both evaluate the expression till it becomes a number (or a null).